# How to fix 'Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on integer'

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I have running a query to receive a list of e-mails who entered a competition to notify them that the competition has ended and when it will run.

I have looked through the code and cannot see where this fails. I am binding the ID and I am also receiving the correct data back when executing the query.

Here is the function I am running.

```
function notifyEntrants($id, $sendMsg){
    $connect = db();
    $stmt = $connect->prepare('SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(`payer`.`FirstName`, " ", `payer`.`LastName`) AS "Name", `payer`.`Email` AS "Email" FROM `transaction` INNER JOIN `payer` ON `payer`.`DrawID` = `transaction`.`DrawID` WHERE `transaction`.`DrawID` = ?;');
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $drawTitle = getTitle($id);

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $email = $row['Email'];
        $name = $row['Name'];
        // Create the Transport
        $transport = (new Swift_SmtpTransport('smtp.gmail.com', 465, 'ssl'))
          ->setUsername(SITE_EMAIL)
          ->setPassword(MAIL_PASS)
        ;

        $sendMsg .= "<br><br><a href=" . SITE_URL . "entries?id=".$id.">Click here</a> to see the entry list for this draw.";

        // Create the Mailer using your created Transport
        $mailer = new Swift_Mailer($transport);

        // Create a message
        $message = (new Swift_Message("Live draw confirmation for $drawTitle"))
          ->setFrom([SITE_EMAIL => SITE_NAME])
          ->setTo([$email => $name])
          ->setBody($sendMsg, 'text/html');

        // Send the message
        $result = $mailer->send($message);
    }
}

//echo notifyEntrants(15, "test");
```

On a var_dump I get this back `array(2) { ["Name"]=> string(6) "Aidan " ["Email"]=> string(22) "adonnelly759@qub.ac.uk" }` Which is what I would be expecting. Just the one email address and users name.

However this ends up resulting in the error: "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on integer".

Thanks in advance and sorry if this is something simple I just can't get my finger on the button of this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting the SQL results with this line:

```
$result = $mailer->send($message);
```

You need to give one of them a different name.